# Merge two svn branch into new third branch?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

first of all I want to know can we merge two svn branches into new third branch ?
if yes how ?

I have done many research but could not found anything useful. The main thing I am worried about is not to mess up both branch code as both are having various importants changes and I don't want to take chance for wrong code merging.

The only purpose is to merge two branch in new branch is to make sure I do not affect the both branch code as both are valuable code copy.

Once I have new merged branch I will perform all my test and make sure that merged worked correctly and I can go with it.

Comment: Please read [svn help merge](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.merge.html), topic '2-URL merge' and act accordingly to your objectives P.S.: you can't merge two Working Copies and never was and never will be able.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do it like this: Let A and B be your 2 branches, C your new branch and R your repository. All 3 branches need to exist (i. e. [b] already happened in the past). If your C is not already created, try branching revision 0 as C. Then you can use the `svn merge` command in the 3rd syntax (see manual as @LazyBadger stated in a comment above) to merge (see [m] below) A and B into C. Do *not* use the `--reintegrate` option. Merging does not break or close the merged branches; you can still continue developing in A, B and C separately.

From now on you still have your branches A and B, plus your branch C in your working copy contains the merger of A and B. I'm currently not able to test this, but this should work.

```
  [b]   [m]
R--+--A---+---
   |      |
   +--B--+----
   |     ||
   +--C--++---
```